# Chef ignores apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef-infra, vagrant, apt-get

I'm using chef in vagrant to provision a precise32 VM.

The command:

```
execute "apt-get update" do
    command "apt-get update"
end
```

Seems to take no effect.

Vagrant 1.0.3
Virtualbox 4.1.18

Comment: You might want to put `sudo` or `gksu` in front of the command. OR make sure that your application is running with root.

Comment: Adding `sudo` or `gksu` doesn't make any difference. The application is currently running as root.

Comment: Is your virtualbox able to reach the outside world? E.G. can it ping the remote repos?

Comment: do you have the apt recipe included in your run_list?  if so, it already defines a resource called execute[apt-get update] which has an action of :nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using the `bash` resource instead? But I also suggest the apt cookbook.

Answer (score 3):

adding this recipe worked for me (it's an "official" one): https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt